# Associated types and container elements

Tags: haskell, types, containers

I think I may have asked this on Haskell-Cafe at some point, but damned if I can find the answer now... So I'm asking it again here, so hopefully in future I can *find* the answer!

Haskell is *fantastic* at dealing with parametric polymorphism. But the trouble is that not everything is parametric. As a trivial example, suppose we want to fetch the first element of data out of a container. For a parametric type, that's trivial:

```
class HasFirst c where
  first :: c x -> Maybe x

instance HasFirst [] where
  first []    = Nothing
  first (x:_) = Just x
```

Now try and write an instance for `ByteString`. You can't. Its type doesn't mention the element type. You also cannot write an instance for `Set`, because it requires an `Ord` constraint - but the class head doesn't mention the element type, so you cannot constrain it.

Associated types provide a neat way to completely fix these problems:

```
class HasFirst c where
  type Element c :: *
  first :: c -> Maybe (Element c)

instance HasFirst [x] where
  type Element [x] = x
  first []    = Nothing
  first (x:_) = Just x

instance HasFirst ByteString where
  type Element ByteString = Word8
  first b = b ! 0

instance Ord x => HasFirst (Set x) where
  type Element (Set x) = x
  first s = findMin s
```

We now have a new problem, however. Consider trying to "fix" `Functor` so that it works for all container types:

```
class Functor f where
  type Element f :: *
  fmap :: (Functor f2) => (Element f -> Element f2) -> f -> f2
```

This doesn't work at all. It says that if we have a function from the element type of `f` to the element type of `f2`, then we can turn an `f` into an `f2`. So far so good. However, there is apparently *no way* to demand that `f` and `f2` are *the same sort of container!*

Under the existing `Functor` definition, we have

```
fmap :: (x -> y) -> [x] -> [y]
fmap :: (x -> y) -> Seq x -> Seq y
fmap :: (x -> y) -> IO x -> IO y
```

But we do *not* have `fmap :: (x -> y) -> IO x -> [y]`. That is quite impossible. But the class definition above allows it.

Does anybody know how to explain to the type system what I *actually* meant?

**Edit**

The above works by defining a way to compute an element type from a container type. What happens if you try to do it the other way around? Define a function to compute a container type from an element type? Does that work out any easier?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, the problem is that it's not clear what the revised `Functor` is supposed to mean. For instance, consider `ByteString`. A `ByteString` can only be mapped by replacing each `Word8` element with an element *of the same type*. But `Functor` is for *parametric* mappable structures. There are really two conflicting notions of mapping here:

- Rigid mapping (i.e. transforming each element of a structure without changing its type)
- Parametric mapping (i.e. transforming each element of a structure to any type)

So, in this case, you can't explain to the type system what you meant, because it doesn't make much sense. You can, however, change what you mean :)

Rigid mapping is easy to express with type families:

```
class RigidMap f where
  type Element f :: *
  rigidMap :: (Element f -> Element f) -> f -> f
```

As far as parametric mapping, there are multiple ways to do it. The simplest way would be to retain the current `Functor` as-is. Together, these classes covers structures like `ByteString`, `[]`, `Seq`, and so on. However, they all fall down on `Set` and `Map`, because of the `Ord` constraint on values. Happily, the [constraint kinds](http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/?p=127) extension coming in GHC 7.4 lets us fix this problem:

```
class RFunctor f where
  type Element f a :: Constraint
  type Element f a = ()  -- default empty constraint
  fmap :: (Element f a, Element f b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Here, we're saying that every instance should have an associated *typeclass constraint*. For instance, the Set instance will have `Element Set a = Ord a`, to denote that `Set`s can only be constructed if an `Ord` instance is available for the type. Anything that can appear on the left hand of `=>` is accepted. We can define our previous instances exactly as they were, but we can also do `Set` and `Map`:

```
instance RFunctor Set where
  type Element Set a = Ord a
  fmap = Set.map

instance RFunctor Map where
  type Element Map a = Ord a
  fmap = Map.map
```

However, it's pretty annoying to have to use two separate interfaces for rigid mapping and restricted parametric mapping. In fact, isn't the latter a generalisation of the former? Consider the difference between `Set`, which can only contain instances of `Ord`, and `ByteString`, which can only contain `Word8`s. Surely we can express that as just another constraint?

We apply the same trick done to `HasFirst` (i.e. give instances for the whole structure and use a type family to expose the element type), and introduce a new associated constraint family:

```
class Mappable f where
  type Element f :: *
  type Result f a r :: Constraint
  map :: (Result f a r) => (Element f -> a) -> f -> r
```

The idea here is that `Result f a r` expresses the constraints it needs on the value type (like `Ord a`), and *also* constrains the resulting container type however it needs to; presumably, to ensure it has the type of a same-sort-of-container of `a`s. For instance, `Result [a] b r` will presumably require that `r` is `[b]`, and `Result ByteString b r` will require that `b` is `Word8`, and `r` is `ByteString`.

Type families already give us what we need to express "is" here: a type equality constraint. We can say `(a ~ b) => ...` to require that `a` and `b` are the same type. We can, of course, use this in constraint family definitions. So, we have everything we need; on to the instances:

```
instance Mappable [a] where
  type Element [a] = a
  type Result [a] b r = r ~ [b]
  -- The type in this case works out as:
  --   map :: (r ~ [b]) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> r
  -- which simplifies to:
  --   map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
  map = Prelude.map

instance Mappable ByteString where
  type Element ByteString = Word8
  type Result ByteString a r = (a ~ Word8, r ~ ByteString)
  -- The type is:
  --   map :: (b ~ Word8, r ~ ByteString) => (Word8 -> b) -> ByteString -> r
  -- which simplifies to:
  --   map :: (Word8 -> Word8) -> ByteString -> ByteString
  map = ByteString.map

instance (Ord a) => Mappable (Set a) where
  type Element (Set a) = a
  type Result (Set a) b r = (Ord b, r ~ Set b)
  -- The type is:
  --   map :: (Ord a, Ord b, r ~ Set b) => (a -> b) -> Set a -> r
  -- (note the (Ord a) constraint from the instance head)
  -- which simplifies to:
  --   map :: (Ord a, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> Set a -> Set b
  map = Set.map
```

Perfect! We can define instances for any type of container we want, rigid, parametric or parametric-but-restricted, and the types work out perfectly.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried GHC 7.4 yet, so I don't know if any of this actually compiles or works, but I think the basic ideas are sound.

Comment: Still struggling to comprehend exactly what is going on here... Logically, it's simple. We want a map function that accepts any legal input type, and produces any legal output type. The tricky part is defining which types are "legal" for a given container. (I'm not into this whole "rigid" vs "parametric" distinction.) Can anyone explain what all the "~" characters mean? Or what "Constraint" means?

Comment: I've expanded my answer to hopefully explain things better; I would also recommend reading the blog post I linked for a more thorough explanation of `Constraint`.

Comment: So kind "*" is a normal type, kind "* -> *" is any type constructor, and kind "Constraint" isn't a type at all, it's a type constraint? Is that right?

Comment: Yep, exactly. (Although "type constraint" might be misleading; a single constraint can involve an arbitrary number of types.)

Comment: So "Result" isn't actually a type at all. "r" is the result type, and "Result" just constrains what it may be?

Comment: Yes, the idea is that `Result f a r` expands to a constraint that constrains the element and result types appropriately.

Answer (score 6):

You want [constraint kinds](http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/?p=127), available in ghc 7.4.

Comment: Thank you for _melting my mind!_ I had a feeling this might happen. ;-)